# how can i get friends list from Facebook who using my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I have a requirement like need to fetch the friends who are using my application. Same as Instagram application Find friends from Facebook.

I know this is code which provides the friends list.

```
- (void) getFriendName :(id) sender {

        self.modeString = @"friendName";

        NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())",appDelegate.friendList];
        NSLog(@"query :%@",query);
    //    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, pic_square, current_location, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strlen(birthday_date) != 0 ORDER BY birthday_date",appDelegate.friendList];
        NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        query, @"query",
                                        nil];
        [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                               andParams:params
                           andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                             andDelegate:self];
    }
```

Among these friends list, how can I retrieve only friends using my application?

Answer (score 0):

Do Facebook integration at server side if you are maintaining data at server.

Comment: thanks for your help.....it could be clear undestand to me if you elaborate your answer.

Comment: Do facebook integration at server side. Server will maintain facebook id of each user of this application. Application will send user's fb_id to server. Server will fetch all friends of that user. If any of your friend's fb_id is exists in your server database that means your that friend is using the same application. Like wise server will cheack this for all ur friends and give you the list of facebook friends using the same application

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that I have been using

```
    NSString *isAppUser = usesApp ? @"1" : @"0";
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = %@ AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT %d",
                   isAppUser, limit];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:@{@"q":query} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

You can just remove the limit and just have isAppUser always be @"1"